# MAP DISTINCT VALUES BETWEEN TWO TABLES USING COMMON COLUMN POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have two tables

```
         Table A                        Table B 
id (pk) Name    zipcode         id (pk) Name    zipcode
1         A     100021          B1      T       400031
2         R     400031          B2      U       400031
3         S     100021          B3      W       100022
4         D     100021          B4      Z       100021
5         E     100021          B5      X       100021
6         F     400032          B6      O       400030
7         G     400030          B7      P       400030
8         H     100021          B8      Y       100021
```

the tables above have approximately 30 k data records in each
Need to map Table B records to table A using zipcode as the common key
such that each record from table B is mapped only once in table A

Desired output

```
id (pk) Name    zipcode     id (pk) Name    zipcode
1        A       100021      B4      Z     100021
2        R       400031      B1      T     400031
3        S       100021      B5      X     100021
4        D       100021      B8      Y     100021
5        E       100021     null    null    null
6        F       400032     null    null    null
7        G       400030      B6      O     400030
8        H       100021     null    null    null
```

CODE

```
SELECT              
   TableA.id, TableB.id             
FROM                
   (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TableA) TableA              
   FULL OUTER JOIN              
   (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TableB) TableB              
              ON TableA.pincode = TableB.pincode;
```

ERROR

> "ERROR : invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table Table A
>
> LINE 1:  R JOIN (select distinct id from Table A)Table A on ^ TableA.id
>
> HINT: There is an entry for Table A, but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"

Comment: Isn't `id` unique on each table?

Comment: I am new to this. Pl feel free to let me know if i am making any mistakes in the war queries are raised or commented.

Comment: First try to break down your query and try to convince yourself that it's doing what you expect it to be doing. Personally I don't think what you are looking to do can be done in a simple way and your query is wrong in too many levels to give us anything we can really work with

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback.. I have modified my query basis inputs from SQL pro and Zakir Hossain.. and while i still get duplicate values mapped the errors are removed..

Comment: What if there is a record in B whose zip code does does not exist in A, do you want to see it in the resultset or not?

Comment: The problem is that you want to "use up" a value from table B so it's only matched to table A once. That completely changes the operation from a JOIN to something I'm not aware of, that simple change in requirements changes what you need to do dramatically

Comment: need not be.. i am sure that can be tracked with a vlookup in excel..

Comment: @Seby . . . You have a very valid question here.  However, the code provided is so far from the question, sample data, and desired results that it confuses the question -- it doesn't return the right columns, it has improper `JOIN` keys, it uses `DISTINCT`, but nothing in the question explicitly mentions "distinct".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to "align" the tables.  That is, the matching keys are zip codes and these are duplicated in each table.  You want to match them 1-1, but there is no second key.

The solution is to create a second key, using `row_number()` and then use this with the `full join`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*            
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zipcode ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM TableA a
     ) a FULL JOIN          
     (SELECT b.*
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zipcode ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM TableB b
     ) b              
     ON a.zipcode = b.zipcode AND a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. should work...

`select distinct on (a.id) *
from TableA a
left join TableB b on (a.zipcode = b.zipcode)
order by a.id`

Comment: hey thanks for the input ...but the output file does not get distinct records from table b.. any suggestions ?